# keyerror: "['label'] not found in axis", while using python, even after providing axis = 1 and inplace = True

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using python and while trying to drop a column from a dataset, it is showing a keyerror: "['label'] not found in axis". Although I know you have to provide an axis i.e. 1, but even after providing the axis getting the same error

so this is an example of my code

data = data.drop(['label1','label2'],axis = 1, inplace = True)

But still getting the keyerror for axis.

Comment: Mayhbe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232533/keyerror-when-trying-to-drop-a-column-in-pandas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the drop method returns None if `inplace=True` is passed. So you are actually assigning None to your variable `data`.

The solution would be just write:
`data.drop(['label1','label2'],axis = 1, inplace = True)`

Next, make sure the columns, rows exist in your dataframe by checking using for example the following if statment:

```
if set(['label1','label2']).issubset(data.columns):
       #This should return True
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.drop(['label1','label2],axis = 1)` works in Pycharm